# Malloc returning same value - no double free error

Tags: c, free, undefined-behavior

### ***See Latest Update***

Given the following function, note the location of the call `free(tmp)`:

```
int *power_arr(int *n, int nlength, int exp, int *res_length)
{
    int *tmp, *rt, *bufp;
    int bufp_length, i, dbg_i;

    rt = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000);
    bufp = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000);

    if (!rt || !bufp)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    copy(rt, n, nlength);
    copy(bufp, n, nlength);

    *res_length = bufp_length = nlength;

    while (--exp > 0)
    {
        for (i = *n - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            tmp = sum(rt, *res_length, bufp, bufp_length, res_length);

            if (!tmp)
            {
                exit(-1);
            }

            copy(rt, tmp, *res_length);
           //free(tmp); // produces undefined output?
        }

        copy(bufp, rt, *res_length);
        bufp_length = *res_length;
    }

    free(tmp);

    free(bufp);

    return rt;
}
```

The result of the following main function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int b[] = { 3 };
    int r, i;
    int *rlength, *res;

    r = 0;

    rlength = &r;

    res = power_arr(b, 1, 3, rlength);

    printf("Length = %d\n", *rlength);

    for (i = 0; i < *rlength; i++)
    {   
        printf("i=");
        printf("%d\n", res[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");



    exit(0);
}
```

Is:

```
Length = 2
i=2
i=7
```

My understanding of the first scenario, is that there is a memory leak for every subsequent `tmp = sum(rt, *res_length, bufp, bufp_length, res_length);` call. Which point, I decided to move the call to `free(tmp)` inside the *for* loop. Once moved, I had noticed that the output had changed, as follows:

```
Length = 4
i=1018670
i=4
i=2
i=7
```

I can see that the answer begins at i[3]. Why does the movement of the `free(tmp)` call, cause this effect?

My understanding is that `tmp` becomes a *dangling pointer* after the `free()` call. Then, it is re-assigned a value returned by the function `sum()` - which was retrieved by a call to `malloc()`. Which point, a memory leak would occur by placing the call to `free()` in its original location. As the value of `tmp` will change, only *freeing* the last pointer assigned to it.

---

### Edit:

Below is the code for the supporting functions.

```
int *pad(int *n, int nlength, int new_length, enum SIDE side)
{
    int i, j;
    int *padded;

    if (nlength < 1 || new_length <= nlength)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    padded = calloc(new_length, sizeof(int));

    if (!padded)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (side == LOW)
    {
        j = new_length - 1;

        for (i = (nlength - 1); i >= 0; i--)
        {
            padded[j--] = n[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < nlength; i++)
        {
            padded[j++] = n[i];
        }
    }

    return padded;
}

int *trim(int *n, int nlength, int *res_length)
{
    int i, j;
    int *res;

    for (i = 0; i < nlength; i++)
    {
        if (n[i] > 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    *res_length = (nlength - i);

    res = malloc(sizeof(int) * (*res_length));

    if (!res)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    j = 0;

    while (i < nlength)
    {
        res[j++] = n[i++];
    }

    return res;
}

int *sum(int *n, int nlength, int *m, int mlength, int *sum_length)
{
    int i, tmp, carry;
    int *result, *trimmed, *op1, *op2;
    enum SIDE side = LOW;

    if (nlength == mlength)
    {
        op1 = n;
        op2 = m;
    }
    else if (nlength > mlength)
    {
        op1 = n;
        op2 = pad(m, mlength, nlength, side);
    }
    else
    {
        op1 = m;
        op2 = pad(n, nlength, mlength, side);
    }

    result = malloc(sizeof(int) * (MAX(nlength, mlength) + 1));

    if (!op1 || !op2 || !result)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    carry = 0;

    for (i = (MAX(nlength, mlength)) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        tmp = op1[i] + op2[i] + carry;

        if (carry > 0)
        {
            carry = 0;
        }

        if (tmp >= 10)
        {
            carry = tmp / 10;
            tmp = tmp % 10;
        }

        result[i + 1] = tmp;
    }

    if (carry > 0)
    {
        result[0] = carry--;
    }

    *sum_length = (MAX(nlength, mlength)) + 1;

    trimmed = trim(result, *sum_length, sum_length);

    free(result);

    if (!trimmed)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    return trimmed;
}

void copy(int *to, int *from, int length)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        to[i] = from[i];
    }
}
```

---

### Update:

After implementing the changes suggested in the first post, a *double free* error has begun occurring, to debug, I added the following print statements to the `power_arr()`. The output following shows that `tmp` is being assigned the same value from `sum()`, as it received on the initial call. Why?

Updated code showing debug `printf` statements:

```
    for (i = *n - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        tmp = sum(rt, *res_length, bufp, bufp_length, res_length);

        printf("first tmp = %d\n", tmp);

        if (!tmp)
        {
            printf("tmp was null\n");
            exit(-1);
        }

        copy(rt, tmp, *res_length);

        printf("second tmp = %d\n", tmp);\

        if (tmp != NULL)
        {
            printf("freeing tmp\n");
            free(tmp);
            tmp = NULL;
        }

        printf("tmp = %d\n", tmp);
    }
```

The output:

```
first tmp = 11227072
second tmp = 11227072
freeing tmp
tmp = 0
first tmp = 11227072 <-- Why has the pointer value not changed?
second tmp = 11227072
freeing tmp <-- Double free now occuring.
*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (fasttop):        0x0000000000ab4fc0 ***
Aborted
```

---

### Update:

I believe I have tracked the bug down to the `trim()` function. I have posted the function with a *loop* to execute it 10 times in succession. As you can see in the output, `trim()` - which calls `malloc()`, returns the same pointer value on subsequent calls. Yet, each successive call to free does not trigger a *double free* error. Why is this the case?

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, length;
    int n[] = { 4, 5, 6 };
    int m[] = { 0, 3, 5 };
    int *num;
    int *trimmed, *trimmed_length;

    trimmed_length = &length;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        num = (i % 2 == 0) ? n : m;

        trimmed = trim(num, 3, trimmed_length);

        if (!trimmed)
        {
            printf("trimmed was null\n");
            exit(-1);
        }

        for (j = 0; j < *trimmed_length; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", trimmed[j]);
        }   

        printf("\n");

        free(trimmed); 
    }

    exit(0);
} 

int *trim(int *n, int nlength, int *res_length)
{
    int i, j;
    int *res;

    for (i = 0; i < nlength; i++)
    {
        if (n[i] > 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    *res_length = (nlength - i);

    res = malloc(sizeof(int) * (*res_length));

    if (!res)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    j = 0;

    while (i < nlength)
    {
        res[j++] = n[i++];
    }

    printf("Returned pointer from trim() %d\n", res);

    return res;
}
```

Output:

```
Returned pointer from trim() 39534608
456
Returned pointer from trim() 39534608
35
Returned pointer from trim() 39534608
456
Returned pointer from trim() 39534608
35
Returned pointer from trim() 39534608
456
Returned pointer from trim() 39534608
35
Returned pointer from trim() 39534608
456
Returned pointer from trim() 39534608
35
Returned pointer from trim() 39534608
456
Returned pointer from trim() 39534608
35
```

This also appears to be the behavior in my original question - which triggers a *double free* error. Why is the *double free* error not encountered in this particular situation?

Comment: When your program does not work like the way it is supposed to, create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it.

Comment: Where the definition of `sum` and `copy`? It might be that the error lies there. Please create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example...

Comment: @RSahu This function is part of a series of functions that utilize arrays of ints for calculating 2^1000. I can post the code for the supporting functions. Note, I have tested the code as correct up to 2^1000. It was when I decided that the `free(tmp)` call should be moved, that I noticed the undefined behavior.

Comment: @cryptic, When you try to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, you often end up seeing the problem yourself. If you don't, it will be easier for somebody else to see the problem given such an example.

Comment: @R Sahu. I have tested the supporting functions individually, with successful results. It was when I believed that I spotted a memory leak, and decided to `free(tmp)` before assigning it a new value - in turn, freeing the previous one returned by *malloc* - that I encountered the undefined output.

Comment: You should `free(tmp)` in the same scope where `tmp` is allocated. To my eye, your code looks good. There are two things, tough: `result[0]` may be undefined when the carry is zero, which may throw off `trim` and you should `free(res)` after printing it in `main`. Fixing these passes a Valgrind test. (Not sure how these may be related to the behaviour you observe, though.)

Comment: the function: `sum()` can return NULL, when the call to malloc was successful(), then the allocated memory will never be passed to `free()` resulting in a memory leak

Comment: these lines, in `trim()` are completely unnecessary as the pointer is either NULL or not NULL, so the pointer can be returned in either case: `  if (!trimmed)
    {
        return NULL;
    }`

Comment: Strongly suggest including a few key comments to indicate what each function is trying to perform and use meaningful variable names. 'b', 'r', etc are not meaningful names.   The enum definition only creates a name for 0,  Not real helpful

Comment: I looked at your last program. The code seems correct to me. The same address is returned each time by `malloc` because you have freed the block before calling malloc again, so the same block is available to be used.

Comment: You don't seem to have posted a MCVE yet which shows the problem; this makes life very difficult for someone trying to debug your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of memory leak points and a full bug which is why the free fails [due to double free of the same pointer].

**NOTE:** I've done an update to this answer, but it's too big to fit here, so I've posted it as a second answer

I've joined all files into one so I could compile it [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup], fixed the bug, and annotated all the hot spots [this compiles, but I didn't test it]:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum SIDE {
    LOW
};

#define MAX(_x,_y) (((_x) > (_y)) ? (_x) : (_y))

// perform free if pointer is non-null -- set to null afterwards to prevent
// "double free"
#define FREEME(_ptr) \
    do { \
        if (_ptr != NULL) \
            free(_ptr); \
        _ptr = NULL; \
    } while (0)

int *
pad(int *n, int nlength, int new_length, enum SIDE side)
{
    int i,
     j;
    int *padded;

    if (nlength < 1 || new_length <= nlength) {
        return NULL;
    }

    padded = calloc(new_length, sizeof(int));

    if (!padded) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (side == LOW) {
        j = new_length - 1;

        for (i = (nlength - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
            padded[j--] = n[i];
        }
    }
    else {
        j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < nlength; i++) {
            padded[j++] = n[i];
        }
    }

    return padded;
}

int *
trim(int *n, int nlength, int *res_length)
{
    int i,
     j;
    int *res;

    for (i = 0; i < nlength; i++) {
        if (n[i] > 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    *res_length = (nlength - i);

    res = malloc(sizeof(int) * (*res_length));

    if (!res) {
        return NULL;
    }

    j = 0;

    while (i < nlength) {
        res[j++] = n[i++];
    }

    return res;
}

int *
sum(int *n, int nlength, int *m, int mlength, int *sum_length)
{
    int i,
     tmp,
     carry;
    int *result,
    *trimmed,
    *op1,
    *op2;
    int padflg;
    enum SIDE side = LOW;

    // NOTE: this helps us remember whether to free op2 or not
    padflg = 1;

    // NOTE: here op2 comes from _caller_ -- so do _not_ free it in this
    // function -- _this_ is the cause of the bug
    // case (1)
    if (nlength == mlength) {
        op1 = n;
        op2 = m;
        padflg = 0;
    }

    // NOTE: here op2 comes from _pad_ -- so we do _want_ to free it so it
    // doesn't leak
    // case (2)
    else if (nlength > mlength) {
        op1 = n;
        op2 = pad(m, mlength, nlength, side);
    }

    // case (3)
    else {
        op1 = m;
        op2 = pad(n, nlength, mlength, side);
    }

    result = malloc(sizeof(int) * (MAX(nlength, mlength) + 1));

    if (!op1 || !op2 || !result) {
        if (padflg)
            FREEME(op2);
        FREEME(result);
        return NULL;
    }

    carry = 0;

    for (i = (MAX(nlength, mlength)) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        tmp = op1[i] + op2[i] + carry;

        if (carry > 0) {
            carry = 0;
        }

        if (tmp >= 10) {
            carry = tmp / 10;
            tmp = tmp % 10;
        }

        result[i + 1] = tmp;
    }

    // NOTE: we want to free op2 for case (2)/(3) but we didn't remember
    // how we got it: (1) means no free, (2)/(3) means free
    // only free if this if we called pad, and _not_ if this pointer belongs
    // to caller
    if (padflg)
        FREEME(op2);

    if (carry > 0) {
        result[0] = carry--;
    }

    *sum_length = (MAX(nlength, mlength)) + 1;

    trimmed = trim(result, *sum_length, sum_length);

    free(result);

    return trimmed;
}

void
copy(int *to, int *from, int length)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        to[i] = from[i];
    }
}

int *
power_arr(int *n, int nlength, int exp, int *res_length)
{
    int *tmp,
    *rt,
    *bufp;
    int bufp_length,
     i;

    // NOTE: rt/bufp are memory leaks -- they are never freed
    rt = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000);
    bufp = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000);

    // NOTE: this is a memory leak -- if one is null, but the other is non-null,
    // you must free the non-null one or it leaks
    if (!rt || !bufp) {
        FREEME(rt);
        FREEME(bufp);
        return NULL;
    }

    copy(rt, n, nlength);
    copy(bufp, n, nlength);

    *res_length = bufp_length = nlength;

    while (--exp > 0) {
        for (i = *n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            tmp = sum(rt, *res_length, bufp, bufp_length, res_length);

            if (!tmp) {
                exit(-1);
            }

            copy(rt, tmp, *res_length);

            // NOTE: this will now work because of the padflg changes in
            // sum
#if 0
            // free(tmp); // produces undefined output?
#else
            FREEME(tmp);
#endif
        }

        copy(bufp, rt, *res_length);
        bufp_length = *res_length;
    }

    FREEME(bufp);

    return rt;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int b[] = { 3 };
    int r,
     i;
    int *rlength,
    *res;

    r = 0;

    rlength = &r;

    res = power_arr(b, 1, 3, rlength);

    printf("Length = %d\n", *rlength);

    for (i = 0; i < *rlength; i++) {
        printf("i=");
        printf("%d\n", res[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: calling `free()` with a NULL pointer is ok, `free()` checks for that special case and immediately returns.

Comment: Implementing those changes, a new bug appears to have shown. The call to `FREEME(tmp)` results in a double free now. Why would this happen if *tmp* is being assigned the value of NULL, then re-assigned a new value from the call to `sum`?

Comment: I have added `printf` statements within the `for` loop in `power_arr()` - to display the value of `tmp` (where it is pointing too). It appears that the same value is being assigned after a subsequent call to `sum()`. By executing 2^2, this can be seen - as in the output I have posted.

Comment: Note, by placing a `printf(res)` in `trim()`, I can see that the value returned by `malloc()` is identical on subsequent calls. I will place a snippet of code showing the results.

Comment: I have added a snippet of code that can be copied and run. It shows that the value returned by `trim()` is identical on subsequent calls - even with different input parameters. Now the question is, why is a *double free* error not observed in this case? Shouldn't every subsequent call to `free(trimmed)` trigger a *double free* error, as the value of *trimmed* has not changed?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** I'm adding a second answer here because the new code example is too big to fit as an update to my previous one.

I found a few more issues.  If you run the original test program repeatedly, it gives different [incorrect] answers on each run.  That is, loop on it from a script.

I wasn't able to fix the remaining bug(s) with the existing functions and arguments.  The sheer complexity was adding to the problems.

Once I realized what you were really trying to do (e.g. multiprecision math), I was able to apply several simplifications:

Instead of passing around `int *vals, int *len` everywhere, I created a "big number" `struct`:
- contains pointer to data and length
- length of data buffer can grow/shrink dynamically
- has reference count

You were doing your math in "big endian" mode.  This made it necessary to reallocate frequently (e.g. as in `pad` and `copy`).  This also added to the complexity.  I switched this to use "little endian", which is *much* easier to work with.  And, it's also a bit [considerably] faster.

I also noticed in your power function that you were using `sum` to do what was essentially `rt += bufp;`.  So, I created a version `sumeq` that operated on power's `rt` value directly, which further simplified things.

Note: You can still do it big endian, but most packages I've seen use little.  Still, the base routines to create/grow the struct are endian agnostic, and you could create big endian versions of the little endian functions I created [which came from your big endian functions]

---

Here's the actual code.  It is buildable and runnable.  It will test all versions, including your original code [with the issues].

```
// badfree -- test program

#define TSTDEFALL
// badfree/badfree.h -- badfree control

#ifndef _badfree_badfree_h_
#define _badfree_badfree_h_

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprtf(_fmt...)        printf(_fmt)
#define dbgexec(_exec)          _exec
#else
#define dbgprtf(_fmt...)        /**/
#define dbgexec(_exec)          /**/
#endif

#define dbgleshow(_num,_who)    dbgexec(leshow(_num,0,_who))

#define sysfault(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        printf(_fmt); \
        fflush(stdout); \
        _sysfault(); \
    } while (0)

typedef unsigned int u32;

#if BIGDIG == 1
typedef char bigdig_t;
#elif BIGDIG == 2
typedef short bigdig_t;
#else
typedef int bigdig_t;
#endif
typedef bigdig_t *bigdig_p;
typedef const bigdig_t *bigdig_pc;

// multiprecision number control
struct bignum {
    u32 num_opts;                       // options
    const char *num_tag;                // symbol name
    int num_refcnt;                     // reference count
    int num_curlen;                     // current length
    int num_maxlen;                     // maximum length
    bigdig_p num_base;                  // pointer to vector
};
typedef struct bignum bgn_t;
typedef bgn_t *bgn_p;
typedef const bgn_t *bgn_pc;

// num_opts definitions
#define BGNASTRUCT      (1 << 0)    // struct was allocated
#define BGNABASE        (1 << 1)    // num_base was allocated
#define BGNINITAV       (1 << 2)    // bgninit -- init values
#define BGNINITDUP      (1 << 3)    // bgninit -- init values
#define BGNTRIM         (1 << 4)    // trim number
#define BGNRAW          (1 << 5)    // output number in raw order

#define BGNACQUIRE(_num) \
    bgnacquire(_num)
#define BGNRELEASE(_num) \
    _num = bgnrelease(_num)

#define BGNINIT(_sym,_opt,_len...) \
    _sym = bgninit(#_sym,_opt,_len)

#define BGNASSERT(_num,_opt) \
    do { \
        if (((_num)->num_opts & _opt) == (_opt)) \
            break; \
        sysfault("BGNASSERT: failure -- num=%p num_opts=%8.8X opt=%8.8X\n", \
            num,num->num_opts,_opt); \
    } while (0)

#define BGNASSERT_NOT(_num,_opt) \
    do { \
        if (((_num)->num_opts & _opt) != (_opt)) \
            break; \
        sysfault("BGNASSERT_NOT: failure -- num=%p num_opts=%8.8X opt=%8.8X\n", \
            num,num->num_opts,_opt); \
    } while (0)

enum SIDE {
    LOW
};

#define MAX(_x,_y) (((_x) > (_y)) ? (_x) : (_y))
#define MIN(_x,_y) (((_x) < (_y)) ? (_x) : (_y))

// perform free if pointer is non-null -- set to null afterwards to prevent
// "double free" and use of pointer after it has been freed
#define FREEME(_ptr) \
    do { \
        if (_ptr != NULL) \
            free(_ptr); \
        _ptr = NULL; \
    } while (0)

// test control
struct tstctl {
    int tst_allow;                      // allow test to be performed
    const char *tst_tag;                // name of test
    void (*tst_fnc)(void);              // test function
};
typedef struct tstctl tstctl_t;
typedef tstctl_t *tstctl_p;
typedef const tstctl_t *tstctl_pc;

#define FORTSTALL(_tst) \
    _tst = tstlist;  _tst->tst_tag != NULL;  ++_tst

    int
    main(int argc, char **argv);

    void
    dotests(void);

    void
    dotest(tstctl_p tst);

    void
    usage(void);

    void
    becopy(bigdig_t *to, const bigdig_t *from, int length);

    bigdig_t *
    bepad(const bigdig_t *n, int nlength, int new_length, enum SIDE side);

    bigdig_t *
    betrim(const bigdig_t *n, int *res_length);

    bigdig_t *
    besum(bigdig_t *n, int nlength, bigdig_t *m, int mlength,
        int *sum_length);

    bigdig_t *
    be_power_arr(const bigdig_t *n, int nlength, int exp, int *res_length);

    void
    betest_orig(void);

    void
    betest_trim(void);

    void
    betest_show(bigdig_pc num,int len,const char *sym);

    bgn_p
    bgninit(const char *tag,u32 opt,int maxlen,...);

    bgn_p
    bgnacquire(bgn_p num);

    bgn_p
    bgnrelease(bgn_p num);

    void
    bgngrow(bgn_p num,int newlen);

    void
    bgnshrink(bgn_p num);

    void
    lecopy(bgn_p to,bgn_pc from);

    bgn_p
    lepad(bgn_pc num,int newlen);

    void
    letrim(bgn_p num);

    int
    _letrim(bgn_pc num);

    void
    leshow(bgn_pc num,u32 opt,const char *who);

    void
    lesumeq(bgn_p result,bgn_p op2);

    bgn_p
    le_power_arr_eq(bgn_pc num,int exp);

    bgn_p
    lesumrt(bgn_p n,bgn_p m);

    bgn_p
    le_power_arr_rt(bgn_pc n, int exp);

    void
    letest_lesumrt(void);

    void
    letest_lesumeq(void);

    void
    _sysfault(void);

    void
    reverse(bigdig_p arr, int length);

#define TSTDEF(_on,_fnc) \
    { .tst_allow = _on, .tst_tag = #_fnc, .tst_fnc = _fnc }

#ifdef TSTDEFALL
tstctl_t tstlist[] = {
    TSTDEF(1,betest_orig),
    TSTDEF(0,betest_trim),
    TSTDEF(1,letest_lesumrt),
    TSTDEF(1,letest_lesumeq),
    { .tst_tag = NULL }
};
#endif

#endif

// badfree/bemath -- big endian math

void
becopy(bigdig_t *to, const bigdig_t *from, int length)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        to[i] = from[i];
}

bigdig_t *
bepad(const bigdig_t *n, int nlength, int new_length, enum SIDE side)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    bigdig_t *padded;

    if (nlength < 1 || new_length <= nlength) {
        sysfault("bepad: length fault -- nlength=%d new_length=%d\n",
            nlength,new_length);
        return NULL;
    }

    padded = calloc(new_length,sizeof(bigdig_t));

    if (!padded)
        return NULL;

    if (side == LOW) {
        j = new_length - 1;

        for (i = (nlength - 1); i >= 0; i--)
            padded[j--] = n[i];
    }
    else {
        j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < nlength; i++)
            padded[j++] = n[i];
    }

    return padded;
}

bigdig_t *
betrim(const bigdig_t *n, int *res_length)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int nlength;
    bigdig_t *res;

    nlength = *res_length;

    for (i = 0; i < nlength; i++) {
        if (n[i] > 0)
            break;
    }

    nlength -= i;
    *res_length = nlength;

    res = malloc(sizeof(bigdig_t) * nlength);
    if (!res) {
        sysfault("betrim: null malloc\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    j = 0;
    for (;  i < nlength;  ++i, ++j)
        res[j] = n[i];

    return res;
}

bigdig_t *
besum(bigdig_t *n, int nlength, bigdig_t *m, int mlength,
    int *sum_length)
{
    int i;
    int tmp;
    int carry;
    bigdig_t *result;
    bigdig_t *trimmed;
    bigdig_t *op1;
    bigdig_t *op2;
    int padflg;
    enum SIDE side = LOW;

    // NOTE: here op2 comes from _caller_ -- so do _not_ free it in this
    // function -- _this_ is the cause of the bug
    // case (1)
    if (nlength == mlength) {
        op1 = n;
        op2 = m;
        padflg = 0;
    }

    // NOTE: here op2 comes from _pad_ -- so we do _want_ to free it so it
    // doesn't leak
    // case (2)
    else if (nlength > mlength) {
        op1 = n;
        op2 = bepad(m, mlength, nlength, side);
        padflg = 1;
    }

    // case (3)
    else {
        op1 = m;
        op2 = bepad(n, nlength, mlength, side);
        padflg = 2;
    }

    result = malloc(sizeof(bigdig_t) * (MAX(nlength, mlength) + 1));

    if (!op1 || !op2 || !result) {
        sysfault("besum: null fault -- padflg=%d op1=%p op2=%p result=%p\n",
            padflg,op1,op2,result);
        if (padflg)
            FREEME(op2);
        FREEME(result);
        return NULL;
    }

    carry = 0;

    for (i = (MAX(nlength, mlength)) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        tmp = op1[i] + op2[i] + carry;

        if (carry > 0)
            carry = 0;

        if (tmp >= 10) {
            carry = tmp / 10;
            tmp = tmp % 10;
        }

        result[i + 1] = tmp;
    }

    // NOTE: we want to free op2 for case (2)/(3) but we didn't remember
    // how we got it: (1) means no free, (2)/(3) means free
    // only free if this if we called bepad, and _not_ if this pointer belongs
    // to caller
    if (padflg)
        FREEME(op2);

    if (carry > 0)
        result[0] = carry;

    *sum_length = (MAX(nlength, mlength)) + 1;

    trimmed = betrim(result, sum_length);

    FREEME(result);

    return trimmed;
}

bigdig_t *
be_power_arr(const bigdig_t *n, int nlength, int exp, int *res_length)
{
    bigdig_t *tmp;
    bigdig_t *rt;
    bigdig_t *bufp;
    int bufp_length;
    int i;

    // NOTE: rt/bufp are memory leaks -- they are never freed
    rt = malloc(sizeof(bigdig_t) * 1000);
    bufp = malloc(sizeof(bigdig_t) * 1000);

    // NOTE: this is a memory leak -- if one is null, but the other is non-null,
    // you must free the non-null one or it leaks
    if (!rt || !bufp) {
        FREEME(rt);
        FREEME(bufp);
        return NULL;
    }

    becopy(rt, n, nlength);
    becopy(bufp, n, nlength);

    *res_length = bufp_length = nlength;

    while (--exp > 0) {
        for (i = *n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            tmp = besum(rt, nlength, bufp, bufp_length, res_length);

            if (tmp == NULL)
                sysfault("be_power_arr: null besum return\n");

            nlength = *res_length;
            becopy(rt, tmp, nlength);

            // NOTE: this will now work because of the padflg changes in
            // besum
#if 0
            // free(tmp); // produces undefined output?
#else
            FREEME(tmp);
#endif
        }

        becopy(bufp, rt, *res_length);
        bufp_length = *res_length;
    }

    FREEME(bufp);

    return rt;
}
// badfree/betest -- big endian tests

void
betest_orig(void)
{
#if 1
    bigdig_t b[] = { 3 };
#else
    const bigdig_t b[] = { 3 };
#endif
    int rlength;
    int exp;
    bigdig_t *res;

    exp = 3;
    printf("\n");
    printf("betest_orig: exp=%d\n",exp);

    betest_show(b,1,"b");

    rlength = 0;
    res = be_power_arr(b, 1, exp, &rlength);

    betest_show(res,rlength,"res");

    FREEME(res);
}

void
betest_trim(void)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int length;
    const bigdig_t n[] = { 4, 5, 6 };
    const bigdig_t m[] = { 0, 3, 5 };
    const bigdig_t *num;
    bigdig_t *trimmed;

    printf("\n");
    printf("betest_trim:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        num = (i % 2 == 0) ? n : m;

        length = 3;
        trimmed = betrim(num, &length);

        if (!trimmed)
            sysfault("betest_trim: trimmed was null\n");

        printf("pass %d: num=%p trimmed=%p\n",i,num,trimmed);
        for (j = 0; j < length; j++)
            printf(" %d", trimmed[j]);
        printf("\n");

        FREEME(trimmed);
    }
}

// betest_show -- show number
void
betest_show(bigdig_pc num,int len,const char *sym)
{
    int i;

    printf("  sym %s length %d --",sym,len);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf(" %d",num[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
// badfree/bgn -- big number control

// bgninit -- create new number
bgn_p
bgninit(const char *tag,u32 opt,int maxlen,...)
// opt -- options (BGNINIT* -- has initializer data)
// maxlen -- length of number
{
    va_list ap;
    int i;
    bgn_pc from;
    bgn_p num;

    va_start(ap,maxlen);

    num = calloc(1,sizeof(bgn_t));

    opt |= BGNASTRUCT;
    opt |= BGNABASE;
    num->num_opts = opt;

    num->num_tag = tag;

    num->num_refcnt = 1;

    if (maxlen <= 0)
        maxlen = 1;

    from = NULL;
    if (opt & BGNINITDUP) {
        from = va_arg(ap,bgn_pc);
        maxlen = MAX(maxlen,from->num_curlen);
    }

    num->num_maxlen = maxlen;
    num->num_base = calloc(maxlen,sizeof(bigdig_t));

    // initialize from varargs
    if (opt & BGNINITAV) {
        for (i = 0;  i < maxlen;  ++i)
            num->num_base[i] = va_arg(ap,int);
        num->num_curlen = maxlen;
    }

    // initialize by cloning data
    if (opt & BGNINITDUP) {
        maxlen = from->num_curlen;
        for (i = 0;  i < maxlen;  ++i)
            num->num_base[i] = from->num_base[i];
        num->num_curlen = maxlen;
    }

    va_end(ap);

    return num;
}

// bgnacquire -- increment reference count
bgn_p
bgnacquire(bgn_p num)
{

    num->num_refcnt += 1;

    return num;
}

// bgnrelease -- decrement reference count and deallocate
bgn_p
bgnrelease(bgn_p num)
{

    if (--num->num_refcnt == 0) {
        if (num->num_opts & BGNABASE)
            FREEME(num->num_base);

        if (num->num_opts & BGNASTRUCT)
            FREEME(num);

        // this zaps caller's pointer
        num = NULL;
    }

    return num;
}

// bgngrow -- grow allocated number to given length
void
bgngrow(bgn_p num,int newlen)
{
    int growlen;
    int maxlen;
    int i;

    BGNASSERT(num,BGNABASE);

    maxlen = num->num_maxlen;
    growlen = newlen - maxlen;

    if (growlen > 0) {
        maxlen += growlen;

        num->num_base = realloc(num->num_base,sizeof(bigdig_t) * maxlen);

        // zero extend the new area
        for (i = num->num_maxlen;  i < maxlen;  ++i)
            num->num_base[i] = 0;

        num->num_maxlen = maxlen;
    }
}

// bgnshrink -- shrink allocated number to current length
void
bgnshrink(bgn_p num)
{
    int curlen;

    BGNASSERT(num,BGNABASE);

    curlen = num->num_curlen;

    if (num->num_maxlen > curlen) {
        num->num_base = realloc(num->num_base,sizeof(bigdig_t) * curlen);
        num->num_maxlen = curlen;
    }
}
// badfree/lecom -- little endian math common

// lecopy -- copy big number
void
lecopy(bgn_p to,bgn_pc from)
{
    int newlen;
    int i;

    dbgprtf("lecopy: ENTER\n");

    dbgleshow(to,"lecopy");
    dbgleshow(from,"lecopy");

    newlen = from->num_curlen;

    bgngrow(to,newlen);

    for (i = 0; i < newlen; ++i)
        to->num_base[i] = from->num_base[i];

    to->num_curlen = newlen;

    dbgleshow(to,"lecopy");

    dbgprtf("lecopy: EXIT\n");
}

// lepad -- clone and pad number
bgn_p
lepad(bgn_pc num,int newlen)
{
    int i;
    int curlen;
    bgn_p padded;

    curlen = num->num_curlen;

#if 0
    if ((curlen < 1) || (newlen <= curlen)) {
        sysfault("lepad: length fault -- curlen=%d newlen=%d\n",curlen,newlen);
        return NULL;
    }
#endif

    BGNINIT(padded,0,newlen);
    if (!padded) {
        sysfault("lepad: bgninit returned null\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // copy existing digits
    for (i = 0;  i < curlen;  ++i)
        padded->num_base[i] = num->num_base[i];

    // zero extend the larger number
    for (;  i < newlen;  ++i)
        padded->num_base[i] = 0;

    return padded;
}

// letrim -- get rid of leading zeroes by adjusting current length
void
letrim(bgn_p num)
{

    num->num_curlen = _letrim(num);
}

// _letrim -- get rid of leading zeroes by adjusting current length
// RETURNS: trimmed length
int
_letrim(bgn_pc num)
{
    int i;
    int curlen;

    curlen = num->num_curlen;

    for (i = curlen - 1;  i >= 0;  --i) {
        if (num->num_base[i] > 0)
            break;
    }

    if (i <= 0)
        i = 1;

    return i;
}

// leshow -- show number
void
leshow(bgn_pc num,u32 opt,const char *who)
{
    int curlen;
    int i;

    if (opt & BGNTRIM)
        curlen = _letrim(num);
    else
        curlen = num->num_curlen;

    if (who != NULL)
        printf("%s: ",who);

    printf("sym=%s ref=%d len=%d/%d",
        num->num_tag,num->num_refcnt,curlen,num->num_maxlen);

    printf(" trim=%s order=%s",
        (opt & BGNTRIM) ? "yes" : "no",
        (opt & BGNRAW) ? "raw" : "flip");

    printf("\n");

    if (who != NULL)
        printf("%s:",who);
    printf("  ");

    if (opt & BGNRAW) {
        for (i = 0; i < curlen; ++i)
            printf(" %d",num->num_base[i]);
    }

    else {
        for (i = curlen - 1;  i >= 0;  --i)
            printf(" %d",num->num_base[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
// badfree/lesumeq -- little endian sum / power (in-place)

// lesumeq -- do x += y
void
lesumeq(bgn_p result,bgn_p op2)
{
    int op2len;
    int i;
    int tmp;
    int carry;
    int maxlen;
    int minlen;

    op2len = op2->num_curlen;
    tmp = result->num_curlen;
    maxlen = MAX(tmp,op2len);
    minlen = MIN(tmp,op2len);

    bgngrow(result,maxlen + 1);

    carry = 0;
    i = 0;

    for (;  i < minlen;  ++i) {
        tmp = result->num_base[i] + op2->num_base[i] + carry;

        if (tmp >= 10) {
            carry = tmp / 10;
            tmp %= 10;
        }
        else
            carry = 0;

        result->num_base[i] = tmp;
    }

    ++maxlen;

    for (;  i < maxlen;  ++i) {
        if (! carry)
            break;

        tmp = result->num_base[i] + carry;

        if (tmp >= 10) {
            carry = tmp / 10;
            tmp %= 10;
        }
        else
            carry = 0;

        result->num_base[i] = tmp;
    }

    result->num_curlen = maxlen;
}

// le_power_arr_eq -- raise number to power
bgn_p
le_power_arr_eq(bgn_pc num,int exp)
{
    bgn_p rtpwr;
    bgn_p bufp;
    int icur;
    int ilim;

    BGNINIT(rtpwr,BGNINITDUP,1000,num);
    BGNINIT(bufp,BGNINITDUP,1000,num);

    ilim = num->num_base[0];
    ilim -= 1;

    while (--exp > 0) {
        for (icur = 0;  icur < ilim;  ++icur)
            lesumeq(rtpwr,bufp);
        lecopy(bufp,rtpwr);
    }

    BGNRELEASE(bufp);

    return rtpwr;
}
// badfree/lesumrt -- little endian sum / power (alloc/return mode)

bgn_p
lesumrt(bgn_p n,bgn_p m)
{
    int i;
    int tmp;
    int carry;
    int maxlen;
    bgn_p rtsum;
    bgn_p op1;
    bgn_p op2;

    dbgprtf("lesumrt: ENTER\n");

    dbgleshow(n,"lesumrt");
    dbgleshow(m,"lesumrt");

    // case (1)
    if (n->num_curlen == m->num_curlen) {
        op1 = BGNACQUIRE(n);
        op2 = BGNACQUIRE(m);
    }

    // case (2)
    else if (n->num_curlen > m->num_curlen) {
        op1 = BGNACQUIRE(n);
        op2 = lepad(m,n->num_curlen);
    }

    // case (3)
    else {
        op1 = BGNACQUIRE(m);
        op2 = lepad(n,m->num_curlen);
    }

    maxlen = MAX(n->num_curlen,m->num_curlen);
    dbgprtf("lesumrt: PAD maxlen=%d\n",maxlen);

    BGNINIT(rtsum,0,maxlen + 1);

    carry = 0;

    for (i = 0;  i < maxlen;  ++i) {
        tmp = op1->num_base[i] + op2->num_base[i] + carry;

        if (tmp >= 10) {
            carry = tmp / 10;
            tmp %= 10;
        }
        else
            carry = 0;

        rtsum->num_base[i] = tmp;
    }

    rtsum->num_base[i] += carry;
    rtsum->num_curlen = maxlen + 1;

    BGNRELEASE(op1);
    BGNRELEASE(op2);

    dbgleshow(rtsum,"lesumrt");

    dbgprtf("lesumrt: EXIT\n");

    return rtsum;
}

bgn_p
le_power_arr_rt(bgn_pc n, int exp)
{
    bgn_p tmp;
    bgn_p rtpwr;
    bgn_p bufp;
    int icur;
    int ilim;

    dbgprtf("le_power_arr_rt: ENTER\n");

    BGNINIT(rtpwr,BGNINITDUP,1000,n);
    BGNINIT(bufp,BGNINITDUP,1000,n);

    ilim = n->num_base[0];
    ilim -= 1;

    while (--exp > 0) {
        for (icur = 0;  icur < ilim;  ++icur) {
            tmp = lesumrt(rtpwr,bufp);
            if (tmp == NULL)
                sysfault("le_power_arr_rt: null lesumrt return\n");

            lecopy(rtpwr,tmp);

            BGNRELEASE(tmp);
        }

        lecopy(bufp,rtpwr);
    }

    BGNRELEASE(bufp);

    dbgprtf("le_power_arr_rt: EXIT\n");

    return rtpwr;
}
// badfree/letest -- little endian tests

void
letest_lesumrt(void)
{
    bgn_p b;
    int exp;
    bgn_p res;

    exp = 3;
    printf("\n");
    printf("letest_lesumrt: exp=%d\n",exp);

    BGNINIT(b,BGNINITAV,1,3);
    leshow(b,0,"letest_lesumrt");

    res = le_power_arr_rt(b,exp);
    leshow(res,0,"letest_lesumrt");

    BGNRELEASE(res);
    BGNRELEASE(b);
}

void
letest_lesumeq(void)
{
    bgn_p b;
    int exp;
    bgn_p res;

    exp = 3;
    printf("\n");
    printf("letest_lesumeq: exp=%d\n",exp);

    BGNINIT(b,BGNINITAV,1,3);
    leshow(b,0,"letest_lesumeq");

    res = le_power_arr_eq(b,exp);
    leshow(res,0,"letest_lesumeq");

    BGNRELEASE(res);
    BGNRELEASE(b);
}
// badfree/util -- utility functions

void
_sysfault(void)
{

    exit(1);
}

void
reverse(bigdig_p arr, int length)
{
    int lhs;
    int rhs;
    bigdig_t tmp;

    for (lhs = 0, rhs = length - 1;  lhs < rhs;  ++lhs, --rhs) {
        tmp = arr[lhs];
        arr[lhs] = arr[rhs];
        arr[rhs] = tmp;
    }
}

int opt_fork;
int opt_T;

// main -- main program
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *cp;
    tstctl_p tst;
    int tstno;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (; argc > 0; --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        case 'f':
            opt_fork = 1;
            break;

        case 'h':
            usage();
            break;

        case 'T':
            opt_T = atoi(cp + 2);
            break;

        default:
            usage();
            break;
        }
    }

    if (opt_T <= 0)
        opt_T = 1;

    for (FORTSTALL(tst))
        tst->tst_allow = (argc <= 0);

    for (; argc > 0; --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        for (FORTSTALL(tst)) {
            if (strcmp(tst->tst_tag, cp) == 0)
                tst->tst_allow = 1;
        }
    }

    for (tstno = 0; tstno < opt_T; ++tstno)
        dotests();

    return 0;
}

// dotests -- perform tests
void
dotests(void)
{
    tstctl_p tst;
    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    for (FORTSTALL(tst)) {
        if (!tst->tst_allow)
            continue;

        if (!opt_fork) {
            dotest(tst);
            continue;
        }

        pid = fork();
        if (pid) {
            waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
            continue;
        }

        dotest(tst);
        exit(0);
    }
}

// dotest -- perform test
void
dotest(tstctl_p tst)
{

    tst->tst_fnc();
}

// usage -- show usage
void
usage(void)
{
    tstctl_pc tst;

    printf("usage: [options] [test names]\n");

    printf("\n");
    printf("options:\n");
    printf("  -f -- run tests in forked child\n");
    printf("  -T<repeat> -- test repeat count\n");

    printf("\n");
    printf("tests:\n");

    for (FORTSTALL(tst))
        printf("  %s\n", tst->tst_tag);

    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: If you like the code, but would like it as separate files, I can post it as a self expanding archive on pastebin